# Lof JSliderNews 1.0 (jQuery), IE9 problem

Tags: jquery

I'm using [Lof JSliderNews 1.0 - Jquery 1.3](http://landofcoder.com/demo/jquery/lofslidernews/index4.html) on my companies website but it only seems to work sporadically in IE 9, it seems to work in every other browser. Is anyone else using the slider and tested it with IE9?

[I'm using it here](http://www.desworkdev.co.uk/).

Cheers

Wayne.

Comment: After a bit of digging around I found adding: isPreloaded     : false, made it wotk in IE9

$(document).ready( function(){ 
   $obj = $('#slidecontent').lofJSidernews( { interval : 4000,
   easing   : 'easeInOutQuad',
   duration  : 1200,
   auto    : true,
   isPreloaded     : false,   // for IE9
   maxItemDisplay  : 3,
   startItem  : 0,
   navPosition     : 'horizontal', // horizontal
   navigatorHeight : 15,
   navigatorWidth  : 25,
   mainWidth:920} );
  })

Comment: I have the same issue.. Thanks a lot for sharing! you saved me the day.. Just including " isPreloaded:false " resolved the issue

Answer (score 5):

Just by updating the "isPreloaded: false" works great in IE9. Thanks @wayne I'm just updating the working code below:

```
$(document).ready( function(){   
  $obj = $('#slidecontent').lofJSidernews({ 
    interval : 4000, 
    easing : 'easeInOutQuad',
    duration : 1200, 
    auto : true,
    isPreloaded : false, // for IE9 
    maxItemDisplay : 3, 
    startItem : 0, 
    navPosition : 'horizontal', // horizontal 
    navigatorHeight : 15, 
    navigatorWidth : 25, 
    mainWidth:920
  }); 
})
```

Comment: Wish we'd looked here sooner.  Thanks guys!  BTW- what does isPreloaded do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Bt after added ispreloaded property it is not working in ie 7